# How where condition lumen (Laravel) working?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

My code

```
$query = $this->newQuery();
$value = $query->select(['id','text', 'author'])->where('id','=','2')->toSql();
```

but `$value` response :

```
select `id`, `text`, `author` from `quotes` where `id` = ?
```

i think `$value` will be response that :

`` select `id`, `text`, `author` from `quotes` where `id` = 2 ``

my `app.php` already have this code 
`$app->withEloquent();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all correct. Laravel is showing you the prepared QUERY not the bound parameters.

The way it works is, it first compiles the SQL from Eloquent methods (select, where, ...), and once it's done compiling the syntax, it fills the parameters in place of question marks.

If you'd like to get the query and the parameters, you could try the following:

```
// enable logging
\DB::enableQueryLog(); 

// listen to database queries
\DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bindings);
    var_dump($time);
});

// run a query
$query->select(['id','text', 'author'])->where('id','=','2')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :D